# JPA entity relations are not populated after .persist()

Tags: jpa

this is a sample of my two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Post implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderBy("revision DESC")
    public List<PostRevision> revisions;

@Entity(name="post_revision")
public class PostRevision implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    public Post post;

    private Integer revision;

    @PrePersist
    private void prePersist() {
        List<PostRevision> list = post.revisions;

        if(list.size() >= 1)
            revision = list.get(list.size() - 1).revision + 1;
        else
            revision = 1;
    }
```

So, there's a "post" and it can have several revisions. During persisting of the revision, entity takes a look at the list of the existing revisions and finds the next revision number. Problem is that Post.revisions is NULL but I think it should be automatically populated. I guess there's some kind of problem in my source code but I don't know where. Here's my "persistence" code:

```
Post post = new Post();
PostRevision revision = new PostRevision();
revision.post = post;

em.persist(post);
em.persist(revision);
em.flush();
```

I think that after persisting "post", it becomes "managed" and all the relations should be populated from now on.

Thanks for help!

(Note: public attributes are just for demonstration)

Answer (score 1):

No. Hibernate will populate the relationships when loading entities from the database. But when you persist or change them, it's your responsibility to maintain the relationships, at both sides.

Since Hibernate entities are also POJOs that you will use in other layers and in unit tests, you should make sure that invariants are OK. For example, the list of revisions should never be null. It should be empty initially.

Comment: Thanks for answer. However, how do I make, in my case EclipseLink, to load the entity from database? Do I use EntityManager.find() to do that? I tried that too but it doesn't work either (revisions is still null).

Answer (score 1):

Convert your `Post` entity to:

```
@Entity
public class Post implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderBy("revision DESC")
    public List<PostRevision> revisions = new ArrayList<PostRevision>();

    public void addRevision(PostRevision revision) {
        if (post.revisions.isEmpty()) {
            revision.setRevision(1);
        } else {
            revision.setRevision(post.revisions.get(post.revisions.size() - 1));
        }
        revision.setPost(this);
        getRevisions().add(revision);
    }
}
```

And make sure you use addRevision when you want to add a revision to a post. With this solution you should also remove the `@PrePersist` listener.